# Issue on redux-oidc signoutRedirect

Tags: reactjs, single-sign-on, identityserver3, oidc-client-js, redux-oidc

Question / Issue

I'm using Identity Server for Single Sign On, my Client application is in ReactJs embedded with Redux. I'm using **`redux-oidc`** npm node module to implement the Identity Server functionality as mentioned in https://github.com/IdentityModel/oidc-client-js/wiki

My oidc config is

```
var settings = {
    authority: 'https://localhost:2025/core',
    client_id: 'TVA',
    silent_redirect_uri: 'http://localhost:3000/silent-renew.html',
    post_logout_redirect_uri: 'http://localhost:3000',
    redirect_uri: `http://localhost:3000/callback`,
    response_type: 'id_token token',
    scope: 'openid payroll',
    acr_values: `tenant:Payroll`,
    accessTokenExpiringNotificationTime: 4,
    automaticSilentRenew: true,
    filterProtocolClaims: true
};
```

If I use the in-built method **`signoutRedirect`**, its again redirecting to the application's initial landing page, but if I directly trigger the end session it redirects to the Identity Server Login Page (i.e., Once the application is successfully logout, the Identity Server redirects to the root URI and then it redirects to the Login page).

**Issue: Its not Signout the application**

```
userManager.signoutRedirect()
    .catch(function (error) {
        console.error('error while signing out user', error);
    });
```

**Fine: Signout's perfectly**

```
const path = 'https://localhost:2025/core/connect/endsession?id_token_hint=${token}&post_logout_redirect_uri=http://localhost:3000';
document.location.href = path;
```

Kindly assist me how to signout using `userManager.signoutRedirect()` ???

Comment: i think the solution is changing authority to **'https://localhost:2025/'**... pls try this out